# In an ER diagram, do all entities need to be connected?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

I am building a model DB of an online store. I have obvious tables such as `Customers`, `Stores`, `Products`, etc...

I made an ER diagram, but I realized that my `Employees` table is sitting out by itself and is not in a relationship with anything else.

#### Questions

- Is this allowed/normal?
- Or must I create a relationship with something?

Comment: Ask yourself whats the purpose of employees in an online store and try to create connection. Having sitting by itself is pretty much pointless.

Comment: @S4V1N The purpose of the employee table is just to allow them to "virtually help the customer" by helping them search for a product online. When an employee logs in, they have a search bar in their interface that allows them to do this. The Employee table has emp_ID, email, password. I can't really think of a way to connect this to my other tables. But really my question is if it's ok to just leave that table sitting over there by it's lonesome ***for an ER Diagram***.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/J3Bux

Comment: From what i can understand customers need to communicate with employees  somehow. You can create a table that records that. Table "Tickets" or whichever name you pick. Employees & Customers ID, and other metadata related to the conversation they had. Eventually you might wanna check if your employees are doing anything...

Comment: If there is no relationship between one table/group of tables and another, that may be a candidate for data that could be stores in a separate database/schema (possibly even on a separate server). As @S4V1N notes, you should consider why you need this data, and determine if it's possible/likely for the data to *eventually* be connected to the rest of the diagram. As far as the actual diagram itself goes, I have seen ER-type diagrams that include such separate groups of tables, but if (for instance) you're going to be graded on this, I can't say if it's "right" or not.